# Remove UISearchController search bar background when active

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to customize the appearance of the `UISearchController` in Swift.

For now I changed the font and color of both placeholder and search text and changed the clear text button image.

I need to remove the background of the search bar (set it to .clear) and set a shadow to the navigation controller bar **only when it's active** (clicked).

How can I achieve this?

I tried to do this to set the shadow in the navigation controller inside `filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String)` but it's not working:

```
// Restore navigation bar line and set shadow
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.applyShadow(color: ViewUtil.color(red: 0, green: 49, blue: 105, alpha: 1), alpha: 0.1, x: 0, y: 6, blur: 9, spread: 0)
```

**EDIT:**

Non-active (this is currently correct):
[image: Search non-active]

Active (what I have):
[image: Search active]

What I want only when search is active:
[image: What I want when search active]

Comment: Please add UI what you want and what you have.

Comment: @SagarChauhan see edit